# How many duas in azkar

Tags: dua, dhikr

Are we supposed to read all the duas Of morning and evening azkar or choose some of the duas I wanted to know about. Jazakallahu khair how many duas should I try to recite?

Answer (score 1):

As adhkar are a recommendation you have the free choice.
You should only follow the recommendations of the based ahadith, for example if there's an amount of repetition you should do it as stated. Else there's no limitation nor a minimum.